# How to disable smooth scrolling in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

When I scroll with my mousewheel, it draws many intermediate steps, and I want it to only draw the immediate destination. It's a bit laggy otherwise.

I tried intercepting `wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL` with `event.StopPropagation()` and doing `.Scroll()` manually, but it still scrolls by itself, `StopPropagation()` doesn't work.

The version of wxPython is 2.9. The widget is `wx.ScrolledWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to adjust the size of a scroll event:

> SetScrollRate(self, xstep, ystep)
>   Set the horizontal and vertical scrolling increment only.
>
> See the pixelsPerUnit parameter in SetScrollbars .
>
> Parameters:
>   xstep (int) –
>   ystep (int) –

Coupled with the font size and the number of items in the window, this can of course be variable.

Note:

> StopAutoScrolling(self)
>   Stop generating the scroll events when mouse is **held outside the window**

and:

> StopPropagation(self)
>   **Stop the event from propagating to its parent window.**

Not stop the event itself

Comment: Doesn't stop autoscroll, but at least it scrolls faster and further now.

Comment: See my edit about `StopPropagation`. Have you tried `event.Skip()` ?

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. `event.Veto()` doesn't work either, `AttributeError: 'MouseEvent' object has no attribute 'Veto'`